# Cannot update OS due to disk storage space limitations

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, operating-systems, storage

I need to update to the latest version of Windows 10 but cannot do this due to limited space on my C: drive.

It says I need to free up at least 6GB before I can install (and install the new stuff on a separate drive, of course).

This is not a possibility for me since the majority of files on the C: drive taking up space are system files which I cannot delete!

What should I do?

Comment: You mean apart from get a bigger drive? 6GB free space is **critically** low on any drive.  10-15% space is essential - ironically, you need to leave even more on a tiny drive, 128GB SSD etc.

Comment: Its not likely that the system files are occupying everything. You probably have too many programs installed. The swap file can be 8192MB, the downloads folder, desktop folder. documents and other general folders may contain a lot of megabytes too.

Comment: @Tetsujin My C drive is only about 60 GB big I think

Comment: @CFCBazarcom No. I have moved almost every single program to my other drives. The problem is that almost all the space is taken up by files I cannot move or delete. I don't understand why it needs space on the C drive to install something into the D drive

Comment: Presumably you have manually partitioned your drive that way as opposed to the drive itself has only that capacity. This was a very poor decision, on many levels.

Comment: What cleanup have you done? What type of drive is C:? Most of HDD? A very small SSD? A (too) small partition of the HDD?

Comment: With me `C:\Windows` Windows 10 version 2004 takes about half of your space. I suggest in Explorer to right-click the disk C, select Properties, and click Disk Clean-up. All the displayed items should be much less than 1 GB. Select your items and click "Clean up system f‌iles".

Comment: Hi, the following link might be helpful to you: https://www.windowscentral.com/best-ways-to-free-hard-drive-space-windows-10#free-space-using-storage-sense

Comment: @Tetsujin No. It is just an old computer

Comment: 100 GB is the minimum for Windows 7/10. I know what the official statement is, this is my statement.

Comment: @Featherball Has `cleanmgr /VERYLOWDISK` command helped you?

Answer (score 4):

Run ***Command Prompt*** as administrator and type `cleanmgr /VERYLOWDISK`, and hit enter. This command will launch ***Disk Cleanup*** with "all boxes selected". It will free up enough of space without the need of using third party software for deleting temp files or doing it manually.

[image]

Be sure to check you don't have any pending updates, because it will delete ***Windows Update Cache***, and it can cause Windows getting stuck while configuring updates, because they have been deleted.

Comment: The one warning I will affix to this answer is this will by default depending on which version of Windows 10 you are currently running includes the user profile Download folder.  If you are a pack rat like myself this might not be desirable without first performing a backup.